# Install bluefoot on Magento 2.3.0 Commerce

Tags: magento2.3, bluefootcms

When I try to install gene/bluefoot on Magento EE 2.3.0 with composer I've got this error :

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install gene/bluefoot 1.0.31
- gene/bluefoot 1.0.30 conflicts with magento/magento2-base[2.3.0].
- gene/bluefoot 1.0.30 conflicts with magento/magento2-base[2.3.0].
- magento/magento2-base 2.3.0 conflicts with gene/bluefoot[1.0.30].
- Installation request for gene/bluefoot ^1.0 -> satisfiable by gene/bluefoot[1.0.30, 1.0.31].
- Installation request for magento/magento2-base (locked at 2.3.0) -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.3.0].
```

I followed documentation by typing :

```
composer require gene/bluefoot:^1.0
```

I saw in composer.json of magento2-base this line :

```
"conflict": {
    "gene/bluefoot": "*"
 }
```

Does someone already install this module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[2.3.1 will introduce the pagebuilder](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-2.3-new-tools-fuel-your-growth-2019) which will replace Bluefoot. But pagebuilder is not available in 2.3.0

If you want 2.3.0 you will have to stick with the plain CMS editor.

## OR

which is kind of hacky... fork Magento 2.3.0 and remove the restriction for bluefoot in the composer.json. Then require your forked repo instead of the official one.

### But Bluefoot might not work properly!

There is a reason why you aren't allowed to install it.

Comment: While removing the conflict will allow it to install some things will be broken inside Page Builder as we made specific changes in 2.3.1 to enable support.

Comment: @Davethanks for the heads up! Since we now have the actuall pagebuilder available we do not have this bluefoot problem anymore

Comment: How can I remove bluefoot module from magento 1.9.4.2.

Comment: How can I remove bluefoot module from magento 1.9.4.2. I want to also remove eav entity and all relate tables ..._varchar etc, I don't want to execute raw query delete from eav attributes where entity_type_id = ....

Answer (score 0):

If you have access you can install it with the following two steps:

set the stability in your composer.json to:

> "minimum-stability": "beta"

Then install the page builder:

> composer require magento/page-builder-commerce